# How do I use a dependency just for tests?

Tags: move, move-lang, aptos

Move is generally pretty Rust-like, the syntax for using dependencies looks very similar:

```rust
use aptos_framework::aptos_account;
```

As such, I'd expect that if I want to use something only in tests, I'd do this:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
use aptos_framework::aptos_account;
```

However this doesn't work in Move, I suppose because there is no notion of [cfg](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html) (indeed, a search through all the Move code in [aptos-core](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core) finds no use of `cfg`). In that case, how do I use a dependency only for tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close! You can do it like this:

```rust
#[test_only]
use aptos_framework::aptos_account;
```